# PrimeFaces Datatable does not show any style

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

[image]

This is my "datatable". "Role" and "Active" are my headers and "Admin and "+" is the content (a row). This datatable has only one entry.

The style is totally missing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:body>


    <h:form>

        <h:outputText value="Roles  " />

        <p:dataTable var="role" value="#{showRolesBean.allRoles}">

            <p:column headerText="Role">
                <p:outputLabel value="#{role.rolename}" />
            </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Active">
                <p:outputLabel value="+" />
            </p:column>


        </p:dataTable>

        <p:editor />
    </h:form>
</h:body>

</html>
```

Also a normal `<p:inputText>` is correctly rendering!
What have I forgotten? What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add a `<h:head> </h:head>`.